# iOS ScrollView setContentSize not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using Xcode 8, iOS 10. I have Create ScrollView from Storyboard. My Flow is

- viewDidLoad method have Restcall, Which fetch Information from Server.
- On Return, I parsed Response and based on that Create UIElements in Method and then add to one ParentView.
- At last ParentView will be added to ScrollView.

> ```
> [self.scrollView addSubview:parentView];
> self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, parentView.frame.size.height);
> [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, parentView.frame.size.height)];
> ```

When I print Scrollview height after this code, it shows "680" which is more than My View Height. I have tried with "viewDidLayoutSubviews" Method but still the ScrollView is not working.
 Does anyone have any idea why It is not scrolling?

Comment: [see links provided inside here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63858). Probably matter of layout setting.

Comment: Do you use Auto Layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are setting the **scrollview** height and **contentSize** height from **parent view**.

You should do as following :-

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:parentView];

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, parentView.frame.size.height)];
```

Hope this will be helpfull

Comment: Thank You So much you save my day.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting a wrong frame of `UIScrollView`. that's why your content size not working.

Try this,

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:parentView];
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, parentView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable autolayout under "Interface Builder Document" disable: "Use Autolayout"

It is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate UIScrollview contentSize dynamically(depending subviews frame) and set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` async in main thread

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.scrollView.subviews {
           contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                        CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

                        for(UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
                           contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,view.frame);

                           scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set `layoutIfNeeded` before set scrollView's frame.

I have similar situation just like you.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.myCustomScrollView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
```

AutoLayout seems works different with frame position in Xcode8.

just don't know why but it's works for me.